# warning: format '%s' expects argument of type char problem in a simple program

Tags: c, build, format

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

  
int main()
{
    char str1[20];
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s",&str1);
    printf("Your name is %s",str1);
    return 0;
}
```

it outputs fine but the the build messages say

warning: format '%s' expects argument of type char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*) [20]' [-Wformat=]

Comment: Can you tell us which line is showing the error? My guess it's the `scanf` line, and changing `&str` to `str1` will solve it.  Use of an array name automatically decays to a pointer, which is what `%s` in scanf (and printf) expect - no `&` needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str1` has type "array of 20 `char`" (`char[20]`). `&` makes a pointer to the operand. So `&str1` has the type "pointer to array of 20 `char`" (`char(*)[20]`).

But `%s` expects the argument to be "pointer to char" (`char*`) and will store the input characters to consecutive `char` in memory starting with the location that the argument points to. So `&str1` is not the correct type.

Since `str1` is an array of char, `str1[0]` does have just type `char` and is the first element of the array, where you want `scanf` to begin storing to and so `&str1[0]` would for example have type `char*` and point to the correct `char`.

Instead you can also just write `str1` instead of `&str1[0]`, because arrays will generally (but not when `&` is applied directly to them) decay to pointers to the first element automatically.

---

It works exactly the same for `printf`'s `%s`, where you are using just `str1` correctly.

Comment: thanks it solved it but i have a question, when can i also use &(name of variable) cause i  read it in a book once and i thought it was the way of doing it

Comment: @Kryspin You cannot use this as general rule. If the variable is an array, as here is the case, then this is wrong. And it would also be wrong if e.g. the variable was of type `char*` pointing to the buffer that you want `scanf` to store into. You need to check what the format specifier in question expects and then think about how to produce that.